# Custom plotrange makes the edgeform of bars in a histogram dissapear

Tags: plotting, histograms

I have two histograms, both of the same data. In one I have adjusted the x axes with plotrange. This is the only difference. In this one however, suddenly the edges around the bars disappear.
Is this a bug? How can i fix this? Can you guys reproduce this problem?
I use mathematica 11.0.

I provided a sample of the dataset, the actual dataset is quite huge.

```
h = {4.090533193601222`*^-18, 5.353544384487416`*^-18,    5.604884982568158`*^-18, -1.062299368932436`*^-18,    5.430258394553261`*^-19, 0.01397074817653086`, -2.021331834648737`*^-18, -1.3662274274834008`*^-18, -3.587177675451973`*^-18,    2.9676022450847787`*^-18, -4.801501645332896`*^-18,    0.021430096635325954`, 0.015972735193928684`,    6.931800809587668`*^-18, 0.013170836894737123`,    2.0276354693644784`*^-18,    0.03941213547895494`, -1.6850428563452604`*^-20, -1.921075550792627`*^-18, 0.782483393686513`*^-18,    8.301028445248647`*^-18, 0.5316568230488358`*^-18,    9.12039994662496`*^-19, -7.916533109748828`*^-18, -1.5226355809978349`*^-18, 1.2405278854721606`*^-17,    0.019780985396967075`, 0.025243348273234652`,    1.0042996987076577`*^-18, -2.9195091354240463`*^-18, -1.0336610445375661`*^-18, -1.3455978089893752`*^-18,    2.3612940018925938`*^-18, 2.814298954961558`*^-18,    1.549153556680915`*^-18,    8.120229190514635`*^-20, -8.735036967087865`*^-19,    8.661841138318455`*^-19, 0.027101596811743858`,    1.5411016838228066`*^-18, -6.963075930344526`*^-18, -5.166655732109912`*^-19, -6.4383831135075665`*^-18, -6.949950507701524`*^-18,   0.01674155445728549`, -1.509597795215209`*^-18,    5.167589911339037`*^-19,    1.5510246818323686`*^-18, -2.7008714829385187`*^-18, -6.680504120708871`*^-19};

Histogram[h, 200, PlotRange -> {{0, 0.02}, Full},  AxesLabel -> {"values"}, PlotLabel -> "title", ImageSize -> 1500]
Histogram[h, 200, PlotRange -> Full, AxesLabel -> {"Eigenvalues"},  PlotLabel -> "title", ImageSize -> 1500]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Normally this would be controlled with `ChartStyle->Directive[EdgeForm[Black]]` and I wouldn't normally jump to calling it a bug since MMA might use some internal heuristic to decide on the base style. But in this case, explicitly specifying the style does not fix the problem, so it probably is a bug in 11.0.

Comment: Sorry, if forgot to mention that I tried that. It did not help. Did you have the same problem? Which version of mathematica did you try? To be specific, I have mathematica 11.0.1.0. If anyone knows a way around this, that would be helpful.

Comment: Tried it on version 10.4 with explicit `ChartStyle`, got the same behaviour. I agree this looks like a bug.

Comment: I reported it as a bug and it got accepted as such. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the opacity is specified. For example, I have had disappearing edge forms in the past. I solved it using:

```
ChartBaseStyle -> EdgeForm[{AbsoluteThickness[1], Black, Opacity[5]}]
```

Good luck,
Tommy